# Is there any 'FindBugs like' plugin for Adobe Flex Builder or Flash Builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex3, actionscript-2

Is there any 'FindBugs like' plugin for Adobe Flex Builder or Flash Builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only things I know that could be close to what you're looking for are external tools that you plug into your flex project.

MonsterDebugger is very complete debug console :
http://demonsterdebugger.com/

MidnightCoders RIAappuncher is a great tool for monitoring RIAs bugs :
http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/ria-apppuncher/overview.html

Answer (score 8):

flex-pmd seems to be the current winner